# Irreducibility of $X^n-a$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let ${\mathbb K}$ be a subfield of ${\mathbb C}$. Let 
$a\in{\mathbb K}$ such that $X^d-a$ has no root in ${\mathbb K}$,
for any divisor $d>1$ of $n$. Does it follow that $X^n-a$ is irreducible
over $\mathbb K$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Take $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$, $a=-1$, $n = 4$. Observe that $X^2 + 1$ and $X^4 + 1$ have no roots in $\mathbb{R}$, but $$X^4+1 = (X^2 + \sqrt{2}X + 1)(X^2 - \sqrt{2}X + 1)$$

Answer (score 7):

Here is the general theorem on such

**Theorem** $\ $ Suppose $\rm\:c\in F\:$ a field,  and $\rm\:0 < n\in\mathbb Z\:.$

$\rm\quad x^n - c\ $ is irreducible over $\rm\:F \iff c \not\in F^p\:$ for all primes $\rm\:p\: |\: n\:$ and $\rm\ c\not\in -4\:F^4\:$ when $\rm\: 4\ |\ n\:. $

A proof is in many Field Theory textbooks, e.g. Karpilovsky, [Topics in Field Theory, Theorem 8.1.6.](http://books.google.com/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425)

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful result.