# What is the minimum degree of polynomial with $\sqrt[n]{a}$ as a root that has integer coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I am looking for the minimum degree polynomial with integer coefficients that has $\sqrt[n]{a}$ as a root where $n$ and $a$ are integers, and where $a>1$ is not a perfect power. I believe that the minimum degree is $n$, for example $x^{n} - a$ works, but I can't find a way to prove that the degree cannot be less than $n$. Based on my research, it seems like you can prove it through some theorems in Field Theory(like this [Minimal degree of polynomial with $a^{1/b}$ as root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248199/minimal-degree-of-polynomial-with-a1-b-as-root)) but I am looking for a proof that doesn't require that, and uses just basic algebra.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[6]{8}$ is not $x^6-8$. You need to add more conditions on $a$ and $n$.

Comment: Would it be better to say n cannot be a multiple of 4 and $\sqrt[n]{a}$ cannot be simplified?

Comment: Been simplified has not a precise mathematical meaning. If you "simplify" $\sqrt[6]{72} $ to $\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3}$ then what is $n$ now?

Comment: That is a good point. Perhaps a definition could be that $\sqrt[n]{a}$ can be simplified if there exists $m$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt[n]{a} = \sqrt[m]{b}$. By this definition, $\sqrt[6]{72}$ cannot be simplified, but $\sqrt[6]{8}$ can be because  $\sqrt[6]{8} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So $\sqrt 2$ can be simplified? Because there exists $m=6$ and $b=8$ such that $\sqrt 2 = \sqrt[m] b$

Comment: That is true, if we change the definition to require $m < n$, can you see any other issues? Thanks for pointing these mistakes out.

Comment: You can simply write $\sqrt[n] a$ where $a>1$ is not a perfect power.

Comment: I just edited the question to add that in. Thanks again.